# Issue with MaskedEditExtender

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit, maskededitextender, maskededitvalidator

I am using AjaxControlToolkit for .Net 4.0

I am having a form with textbox that displays/accepts date and time in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM format i.e. US date format with 24 hour time format.

I have used TextBox with MaskedEditExtender and the MaskedEditValidator.
Please look at the following code -

```
<p>
        First Date Time : 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="mskDateTime1" runat="server" 
            Mask="99/99/9999 99:99" MaskType="DateTime" TargetControlID="txtDateTime1" 
            UserTimeFormat="TwentyFourHour">
        </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
        <asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="mskValDateTime1" runat="server" 
            ControlExtender="mskDateTime1" ControlToValidate="txtDateTime1" 
            IsValidEmpty="False"></asp:MaskedEditValidator>
    </p>

    <p>
        Second Date Time : 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="mskDateTime2" runat="server" 
            Mask="99/99/9999 99:99" MaskType="DateTime" TargetControlID="txtDateTime2" 
            UserTimeFormat="TwentyFourHour">
        </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
        <asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="mskValDateTime2" runat="server" 
            ControlExtender="mskDateTime2" ControlToValidate="txtDateTime2" 
            IsValidEmpty="False"></asp:MaskedEditValidator>
    </p>
```

For showing the dates in above format i am using format in ToString() as given below -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDateTime1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
            txtDateTime2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
        }
```

The date and time is displayed correctly but when the focus goes out of the textboxes the time changes.

I don't know why this happening.

Please look at the following snapshots -

A) Originally 
[image: Software Genius Inc]

B) Changed after focus out
[image: Software Genius Inc]

Can anybody help me out solve this issue.

Do provide better ideas if any.

Thanks for sharing your wisdom.

Comment: 17:50 converted to 5:50 or 17:50 to 05:11???

Comment: That is the actual issue. I want one shown in first image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i have reply my own question as not received any replies from developers.
I found it is actually an issue with MaskEditExtender. You can check [this discussion](http://forums.asp.net/t/1086284.aspx/1).